# TCP Server & Client Connection with Multiple Device in LAN

Tags: c#, .net

I have scenario like having multiple device listening on TCP Port as below:

1. BarCode Camera (192.168.1.101:10001)
2. Dimension Camera (192.168.1.102:10002)
3. Weighing Sensor (192.168.1.103:10003)
4. PLC Device (192.168.1.104:10004)

There is sensor which is invoking these device and send data to connected client. My challenge is below:

1. How to sync all data with some Guid Taging?
2. TCP/IP is best or some other protocol can be used?
3. Frequency of BarCode Scanning is 2 Seconds

I am able to connect and receiving the data currently using Multi Threading but I need to optimize the same, if you all have any idea on that !!

Comment: "best" is subjective; TCP is pretty general-purpose; I guess it depends on whether you want a stream vs packets, and whether you care about missing / out-of-order data. But honestly, other than the mention of multi-threading: these are design questions, not coding questions; you have the context for that, we don't. Re threading: personally I'd recommend async IO over threads, but even then: for a very small number of clients, sync IO might be tolerable.

Comment: Thanks Mark, can you suggest some implementation logic for the same for Async IO?

Comment: I'd use Kestrel as an async TCP server; it makes an exceptional server and can handle huge volumes of connections without a sweat; I have a blog series on this: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Comment: Why do you want so sync data? Which data has to be synced? Are these devices storing the data somewhere or do the devices communicate with each other?

Comment: Hi, there are several use case, one is parcel automation where barcode cameras sent barcode information, dimension camera sent dimension data and weighing sensor sent weight detail, so how to sync all these data to barcode ID or any unique identifier.